# What would cause SingleEmitter.onSuccess() to generate a NoSuchElement exception?

Tags: rx-java2

I have a `Single` flow organized like this:

```java
getSomething() // returns Single<>
.flatMap(something -> {
   // various things
   return Single.defer( () -> {
     // various other things
     return Single.<SomeType>create(emitter -> {
        // some more stuff
        someCallbackApi(result -> {
           if (result.isError()) {
             emitter.onError( result.getCause() );
           } else {
             // guaranteed non-null data
             emitter.onSuccess( result.getData() ); // this generates NoSuchElement
           }
        });
     });
   })
   .retryWhen( ... )
   .flatMap( data -> handle(data) )
   .retryWhen( ... );
})
.retryWhen( ... )
.onErrorResumeNext(error -> process(error))
.subscribe(data -> handleSuccess(data), error -> handleError(error));
```

In test cases, the callback api `Single` successfully retries a number of times (determined by the test case), and every time on the last retry, the call to `emitter.onSuccess()` generates the exception below. What is going on? I haven't been able to restructure or change the downstream operators or subscribers to avoid the problem.

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: null
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableSingleSingle$SingleElementSubscriber.onComplete(FlowableSingleSingle.java:116)
    at io.reactivex.subscribers.SerializedSubscriber.onComplete(SerializedSubscriber.java:168)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableRepeatWhen$WhenReceiver.onComplete(FlowableRepeatWhen.java:118)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFlatMap$MergeSubscriber.drainLoop(FlowableFlatMap.java:426)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFlatMap$MergeSubscriber.drain(FlowableFlatMap.java:366)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFlatMap$MergeSubscriber.onComplete(FlowableFlatMap.java:338)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableZip$ZipCoordinator.drain(FlowableZip.java:210)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableZip$ZipSubscriber.onNext(FlowableZip.java:381)
    at io.reactivex.processors.UnicastProcessor.drainFused(UnicastProcessor.java:363)
    at io.reactivex.processors.UnicastProcessor.drain(UnicastProcessor.java:396)
    at io.reactivex.processors.UnicastProcessor.onNext(UnicastProcessor.java:458)
    at io.reactivex.processors.SerializedProcessor.onNext(SerializedProcessor.java:103)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableRepeatWhen$WhenSourceSubscriber.again(FlowableRepeatWhen.java:171)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableRetryWhen$RetryWhenSubscriber.onError(FlowableRetryWhen.java:76)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleToFlowable$SingleToFlowableObserver.onError(SingleToFlowable.java:67)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleFlatMap$SingleFlatMapCallback$FlatMapSingleObserver.onError(SingleFlatMap.java:116)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableSingleSingle$SingleElementSubscriber.onError(FlowableSingleSingle.java:97)
    at io.reactivex.subscribers.SerializedSubscriber.onError(SerializedSubscriber.java:142)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableRepeatWhen$WhenReceiver.onError(FlowableRepeatWhen.java:112)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFlatMap$MergeSubscriber.checkTerminate(FlowableFlatMap.java:567)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFlatMap$MergeSubscriber.drainLoop(FlowableFlatMap.java:374)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFlatMap$MergeSubscriber.drain(FlowableFlatMap.java:366)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFlatMap$MergeSubscriber.innerError(FlowableFlatMap.java:606)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFlatMap$InnerSubscriber.onError(FlowableFlatMap.java:672)
    at io.reactivex.internal.subscriptions.EmptySubscription.error(EmptySubscription.java:55)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableError.subscribeActual(FlowableError.java:40)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14918)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14865)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFlatMap$MergeSubscriber.onNext(FlowableFlatMap.java:163)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableZip$ZipCoordinator.drain(FlowableZip.java:249)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableZip$ZipSubscriber.onNext(FlowableZip.java:381)
    at io.reactivex.processors.UnicastProcessor.drainFused(UnicastProcessor.java:363)
    at io.reactivex.processors.UnicastProcessor.drain(UnicastProcessor.java:396)
    at io.reactivex.processors.UnicastProcessor.onNext(UnicastProcessor.java:458)
    at io.reactivex.processors.SerializedProcessor.onNext(SerializedProcessor.java:103)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableRepeatWhen$WhenSourceSubscriber.again(FlowableRepeatWhen.java:171)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableRetryWhen$RetryWhenSubscriber.onError(FlowableRetryWhen.java:76)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleToFlowable$SingleToFlowableObserver.onError(SingleToFlowable.java:67)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleFlatMap$SingleFlatMapCallback$FlatMapSingleObserver.onError(SingleFlatMap.java:116)
    at io.reactivex.internal.disposables.EmptyDisposable.error(EmptyDisposable.java:78)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleError.subscribeActual(SingleError.java:42)
    at io.reactivex.Single.subscribe(Single.java:3603)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleFlatMap$SingleFlatMapCallback.onSuccess(SingleFlatMap.java:84)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableSingleSingle$SingleElementSubscriber.onComplete(FlowableSingleSingle.java:114)
    at io.reactivex.subscribers.SerializedSubscriber.onComplete(SerializedSubscriber.java:168)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableRetryWhen$RetryWhenSubscriber.onComplete(FlowableRetryWhen.java:82)
    at io.reactivex.internal.subscriptions.DeferredScalarSubscription.complete(DeferredScalarSubscription.java:134)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleToFlowable$SingleToFlowableObserver.onSuccess(SingleToFlowable.java:62)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleCreate$Emitter.onSuccess(SingleCreate.java:67)
```

**Solved**:
Many thanks to @dano for pointing out the `retryWhen` behavior when used with `Single`. In this case, the outermost `retryWhen` operator had a bad terminating condition, roughly like:

```java
.retryWhen(errors -> errors.zipWith( Flowable.range(1, maxRetries), ...)
                           .flatMap( zipped -> {
  if (zipped.retryCount() <= maxRetries) {
    return Flowable.just(0L);
  }
  return Flowable.error( new Exception() );
})
```

...`Flowable.range()` will complete when it has generated the last number, which will cause the `Single` to emit `NoSuchElement`. Just bumping the count argument to `Flowable.range()` by one is enough to fix the problem:

```java
.retryWhen(errors -> errors.zipWith( Flowable.range(1, maxRetries + 1), ...)
                           .flatMap( zipped -> {
  if (zipped.retryCount() <= maxRetries) {
    return Flowable.just(0L);
  }
  return Flowable.error( new Exception() );
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is happening because of the way you implemented the callback you passed to `retryWhen`. [The `retryWhen` docuementation states](https://javadoc.io/static/io.reactivex.rxjava2/rxjava/2.1.7/io/reactivex/Single.html#retryWhen-io.reactivex.functions.Function-) (emphasis mine):

> Re-subscribes to the current `Single` if and when the `Publisher` returned
> by the handler function signals a value.
>
> **If the Publisher signals an `onComplete`, the resulting `Single` will
> signal a `NoSuchElementException`.**

One of the `Flowable` instances you're returning inside of the calls to `retryWhen` is emitting `onComplete`, which leads to the `NoSuchElementException`.

Here's a very simple example that produces the same error:

```
Single.error(new Exception("hey"))
    .retryWhen(e -> Flowable.just(1))
    .subscribe(System.out::println, e -> e.printStackTrace());
```

The stacktrace this produces starts with this, same as yours:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableSingleSingle$SingleElementSubscriber.onComplete(FlowableSingleSingle.java:116)
    at io.reactivex.subscribers.SerializedSubscriber.onComplete(SerializedSubscriber.java:168)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableRepeatWhen$WhenReceiver.onComplete(FlowableRepeatWhen.java:118)
```

You don't include any of your code from inside the `retryWhen` calls, so I can't say exactly what you did wrong, but generally you want to chain whatever you do to the `Flowable` that is passed in. So my example above would look like this, if we really wanted to retry forever:

```
Single.error(new Exception("hey"))
    .retryWhen(e -> e.flatMap(ign -> Flowable.just(1)))
    .subscribe(System.out::println, e -> e.printStackTrace());
```

Comment: Each of the retryWhen operators are implemented like: retryWhen(errors -> errors.flatMap(...)) or retryWhen(errors -> errors.zipWith().flatMap(...)). The outermost retryWhen() is driving the retries in question - I'll add some more detail there, but this looks like a good lead